# Adding Pods to Xcode project brakes build

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode10

Forgive me, I am new to IOS Development. I have debugged this for a while now and tried all available solutions I could find. I added Pods to my Xcode project and the build now fails. I verified that after running "pod deintegrate; pod clean" the build works again. When I run "pod install" again and open the .workspace (not the .xcodeproj) - the build fails. I have tried every solution I could find.

**I have already tried:**

- Deleting derived data (many times)
- Restarting computer/xcode (many times)
- verifying that I am opening the workspace, not the project
- cleaning the project and re-building (many many times)
- Deleting the Pod-.framework from the Frameworks folder and reading it to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries
- Editing the build scheme to include Pod-.framework
- Adding the pod frameworks to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries
- Adding the pod frameworks to the Embedded Libraries
- Editing the Framework Search Path in Build Settings
- Building to an actual device and simulator

Heres my **Podfile**:

```
#platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'Burnt' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'MaterialComponents'
end
```

**Versions:**

- MacOS version: 10.13.6
- Xcode version: 10.1
- Swift version: 4.2
- CocoaPods version: 1.6.2

**The Error**:

```
ld: framework not found MaterialComponents
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Helpful **Screenshots**:

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkUyl.png)

[General Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7uRa.png)

[The Evil Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1bey.png)

Comment: remove pod from project then do clean built and after successfully clean and built add your pod again. try this way

Comment: Okay, I commented out the line "pod 'MaterialComponents'" and re-ran pod install. Then I cleaned and built - then the build worked. But then I uncommented the line  "pod 'MaterialComponents'" and re-ran pod install. Now when I clean and build, my build fails :/ (same error)

Comment: can you please share your demo if possible

Comment: What do you mean by Demo? Like create a git repo and share that?

Comment: yes if possible

Comment: Okay done: https://github.com/mgalloway46/burnt/tree/master/Burnt

Comment: I have tried couple of hours but not getting exact problem may be library issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

please check MaterialComponents github version you are using right one or not
or try with
pod try MaterialComponents --> on github page

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your swift version to 5 and compile and then you can change it back to 4.2 ..seems like some xcode linking glitch..

[image: Convert to Swift 5]

Answer (score 0):

Can you compare your Project version(swift_version) and installed pod version are same?
i think this OS issue update your macOS and also update cocoapods.

Try new project to install pods.